# Coffee cup looks foggy after rendering

Tags: lighting, shadows, glass

I’m following BlenderGuru’s donut tutorial, and right now I am modeling the coffee cup. The problem is that the cup looks kind of foggy after rendering (see attached screenshot). There’s a weird black-spot pattern that’s present on the side of the cup and in the cup’s shadow. When I turn off “cast shadow” in the lighting settings, the problem goes away. This makes me think it’s a problem with how the light is interacting with the glass material and casting a shadow.

I’ve tried a lot of different ideas I’ve found online, but nothing has worked so far. Yes, the liquid is scaled up so that it overlaps the cup. And yes, denoising is turned on. Increasing the number of render samples doesn't help.

I really appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: Render size sample? That is not a thing. There’s render tile size, and then there’s number of render samples, and then there’s the size of the rendered image. This looks like a common denoising error…

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, turns out I just needed to increase the number of render samples even more. I was originally rendering at 256 samples, and increasing it to 500 didn't make a noticeable difference (hence why I thought the problem wasn't related). But increasing the number of samples even further to 1000 made a significant improvement, and 2000 virtually solved the issue. Thank you and hope this helps anyone else with this problem.